# How to access data with index outside *ngFor

Tags: angular, typescript, carousel, ngfor

I want to access data outside *ngFor

```
    <mat-carousel timings="250ms ease-in" [autoplay]="false" interval="5000" color="accent" maxWidth="93%"
                proportion="80" slides="3" slideHeight="100%" [loop]="false" [hideArrows]="false" [hideIndicators]="true"
                [useKeyboard]="false" [useMouseWheel]="false" orientation="ltr" maintainAspectRatio="false">
    <mat-carousel-slide #matCarouselSlide *ngFor="let event of myvideo; let i = index"
                  overlayColor="#00000040" [hideOverlay]="true">
                          <video *ngIf="event?.Video" controls style="width: 100%;">
                          <source src="{{event?.Video}}" type="video/mp4">
                          Browser not supported
                        </video>
    </mat-carousel-slide>

***I want to get in this part {{event?.title}}*** 
    </mat-carousel>
```

Please can you share with me any idea? It's possible?

Comment: This is unnatural, I guess, it declared and used as local template variable, why you want to access it outside ? I am pretty sure whatever use case you want to do, can be possible without such kind of hack thing. If you want to display the title outside the video tag or carousal, you can use it there and with css you can do it.

Comment: I can not find a good solution with css, to be responsive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the [source code](https://github.com/gbrlsnchs/material2-carousel/blob/master/projects/carousel/src/lib/carousel.component.ts) - you can use the change output event to save the current slide index in the component

```js
    <mat-carousel ... (change)="currentSlideIndex = $event">
    <mat-carousel-slide #matCarouselSlide *ngFor="let event of myvideo; let i = index"
                  overlayColor="#00000040" [hideOverlay]="true">
                          <video *ngIf="event?.Video" controls style="width: 100%;">
                          <source src="{{event?.Video}}" type="video/mp4">
                          Browser not supported
                        </video>
    </mat-carousel-slide>
       {{myvideo[currentSlideIndex].title}}
    </mat-carousel>
```

```
@Component({
  selector: 'your-component',
  templateUrl: 'your-component.html'
})
export class YourComponent {
  currentSlideIndex = 0;

  slides = [...];
}
```

[Live demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tooltip-material-iakaut?file=src/app/tooltip/basictooltip.html)

Answer (score 0):

@Site, I think you're looking for [ng-container](https://angular.io/guide/built-in-directives#hosting-a-directive-without-a-dom-element) -that not create an additional tag-

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let event of myvideo; let i = index">
  <mat-carousel-slide #matCarouselSlide >...
  </mat-carousel-slide>
  {{event?.title}}
</mat-carousel>
```

But really I think that the "title" should be inside mat-carousel-slide